# How to shorten method that checks if multiplying gives overflow

Tags: java, try-catch, long-integer, integer-overflow

For class I have to write a method that checks if multiplying a certain rational number with an integer results in an overflow or not.

I have written following code and it works but I have a feeling it could be shorter but I don't know how:

```
/**
 * A method for multiplying a rational number with a given number 
 */
public Rational multiply(long factor) {
    try {
        this.numerator = Math.multiplyExact(this.getNumerator(), factor);
        return this;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        try {
            this.numerator = Math.multiplyExact(Math.multiplyExact(this.getNumerator(),this.getNumerator()), factor);
            this.denominator = this.denominator * this.denominator;
            return this;
        } catch (ArithmeticException e1) {
            try {
                this.numerator = Math.multiplyExact(Math.multiplyExact(this.getNumerator(),this.getNumerator()),Math.multiplyExact(factor, factor));
                this.denominator = this.denominator * this.denominator * this.denominator;
                return this;
            } catch (ArithmeticException e2) {
                System.out.println("Overflow");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method does the following:
a = numerator, b = denominator, f = factor

- If "a * f" does not result in overflow than return (a * f)/b
- If it does overflow than check if "aa * f" overflows, if it does not than return (aa * f)/bb
- If it does overflow than check if "aa * ff" overflows, if it does not than return (aa * ff)/bbb

Comment: Why do you think that multiplying a number that overflows with another number it will not overflow?

Comment: You could check if the result of the multiplication is smaller then the input value. If this is true an overflow has occured. This will not handle all cases but you could also perfom a few checks oft the factor. Something like if Integer.MAX_VALUE % rational < factor --> overflow

Comment: I think with BigIntegers you do not have to worry too much for overflows, so unless there are other constraints (like performance problems), I would use them.

Comment: @Michiel here is an example for the BigInteger approach: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/32class/BigRational.java.html Much more clear what happens (and from the outside it is immutable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Integer.MAX_VALUE % d` you will get the number of how many times you can multiply d to get the maximum value and if this value is smaller then your factor the multiplication will overflow.

```
public Rational multiply(Long factor) {
    double d = this.numerator / (double) this.denumerator;
    if(Integer.MAX_VALUE % d < factor){
        //overflow
    } else if (this.numerator * factor < this.numerator){
        //overflow
    }else{
        this.numerator *= factor;
   }
}
```

EDIT: If your Rational object represents a value between -1 and 1 you can be sure that no overflow will happen.

Comment: What is wrong with the Math#multiplyExact (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact-long-long-) in Java8? I think that seems to be a good option.

Comment: @GáborBakos True! But i think num and denom are stored as int and he wants to multiply with a long. So when using multiplyExact the TO has to choose between multiplyExact(int,int) or multiplyExact(long,long).